# ERC1155 NFT transfer using Ethers.js

Tags: nft, ethers.js

I want to transfer ERC1155 NFT from one contract account to another. Does anyone know how to make it work with ethers.js

Answer (score 1):

As every Ethereum contract

- use [Type Chain](https://github.com/dethcrypto/TypeChain) to create contract typings ABI and contract factory in TS
- connect contract to Ethers.js provider
- perform transactions using [Contracts methods](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/getting-started/#getting-started--contracts).
  Probably the response is too generic but the question is generic too.